# SynchronizedMemoryStore has been deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activesupport

Rails is telling me:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Cache::SynchronizedMemoryStore has been deprecated in favor of ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore

Googling [SynchronizedMemoryStore deprecated](http://www.google.com/search?q=SynchronizedMemoryStore%20deprecated&num=30&hl=en&safe=off&oe=ISO-8859-1&prmd=ivns&ei=Ms3dTcySGMjn0QHH5aGcCg&start=0&sa=N&biw=1442&bih=940) finds no discussion or documentation. I'm guessing that `ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore` is now thread safe, but it's a little odd to find zero mention of it anywhere.

Anyone know what the deal is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/rubyonrails-core/ActiveSupport%3a%3aCache%2420consistent/rubyonrails-core/mWmQcOe8uG4/discussion) you might have been looking for:

Answer (score 1):

Alright, found the answer: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ee51b51b60f9e6cce9babed2c8a65a14d87790c8

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemoryStore.html):

> MemoryStore is thread-safe.